# Application requires IP address, need it to go to domain

Tags: networking, dns, ip

We use a (poorly-designed) application that requires the IP address of our corporate office which has a static public IP address. However, when our failover internet kicks in, it obviously has a different static public IP address and then remote connections fail.

If the application would accept a domain name, I would use that with dynamic DNS, but it doesn't accept a domain name.

Is there any way to input an IP address but get to our domain name? I had two thoughts that I haven't tried yet.

1. Set up a local IP address that redirects to our domain name (e.g. 10.0.1.99 goes to local.ourdomain.com). However, I'm not quite sure how I would do this. Set up a Raspberry Pi with a web server maybe.
2. Purchase web hosting with a dedicated IP address and have it redirect to our domain which then could get updated as needed.

Any thoughts on how to achieve this?

Comment: Reverse proxy. Stick it at a fixed address and have it forward packets to the appropriate address.

Comment: Just a Windows program that a vendor has provided to us which sends and retrieves data from our corporate office.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Something like a Raspberry Pi running Nginx as a reverse proxy?

Comment: Nginx, netfilter, ebtables, whatever you need.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I've never configured Nginx but there seem to be plenty of tutorials on setting it up as a reverse proxy and a RPi is easy enough. I'll look into this more.

Comment: You’re going to have to host a reverse proxy somewhere with an IP address that never changes. That will cost money. Have you considered just moving the service to the cloud where redundancy is built in anyways? The cost is probably similar. The other suggestion of using a VPN makes a lot of sense. I don’t see how a reverse proxy is a good solution to this at all.

Comment: Are you using Reverse DNS and referring to PTR records?  I'm guessing probably not (that's a bit more advanced).  That is how "IP address that redirects to our domain name (e.g. 10.0.1.99 goes to local.ourdomain.com)."  I find it much more likely that you have an A record, so local.example.com goes to 10.0.1.99.  Being able to keep that straight may be essential to being able to craft a working solution.  If your software app communicates through a firewall, NAT might be useful.

Comment: @Appleoddity The cost of "host a reverse proxy somewhere with an IP address that never changes" is "buy a raspberry pi and configure it". The device after all needs nothing but a static IP address in the local network (and if that one fails no solution will work). Moving to the cloud is a repeated cost every month, just as a VPN is.

Comment: @Voo either I’m misunderstanding the question or you are. The problem here that I see is that there are external clients trying to connect to a server on-premise. If the company’s public IP changes due to a failover event, the external clients can’t connect.  So you tell me how a reverse proxy hosted on premise is going to solve that?

Comment: @Appleoddity The reverse proxy is simply the implementation of bullet point 1 of the OP. You don't have the raspberry in the corporate office but in the local network where the application is being run. Since that's feasible in the given scenario according to the OP, it's probably the simplest and cheapest solution.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

A reverse proxy is a good idea, but may be limited by protocol.

I'd solve this problem by setting up a VPN (which provides security - if the app is that badly written it does not do a DNS lookup it's probably not using decent crypto either).  Using a VPN means your addresses can all be rfc1918 ( ie private ones ), and the app won't even care when the external addresses change.

Answer (score 0):

A VPN is sort of expensive when you could get a Raspberry Pi or Pi Zero and run Debian on it, and set up iptables on it to masquarade the way you want

Details would depend on how you local network was set up, but the general idea would be to give the Pi two fixed local addresses.

One address would be reserved for administering the Raspberry Pi.  That's how you'd ssh in and alter things if needed.

The other would act as  proxy for the remote primary (or backup).

Packets sent to THAT address could get forwarded using `iptables` as a masquerade to the primary or to the fallback depending on conditions.  NAT would alter the packet's source and destination addresses as needed before re-transmission.

Packets returning get NATed back to the requester.

This should work fine as long as there are no IP addresses embedded deeper in the packets, or cases like classic FTP that establish parallel connections.

Bonus points if you can make the Pi notice that the primary site has vanished and automagically switch to the backup

Comment: I run a vpn for free, i dont see why he couldn't. He isnt hiding his traffic from his ISP. OPENvpn